# How to take a list and format it in a certain way with it repeating?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am wondering about how to format a list in a certain way. I needed to write a program that lists all the primes between two numbers and then have them print out a certain way. I figured out how to list them but I need it to look a certain way.  The way should be this: firstNum:secondNum!thirdNum&fourthNum:fifthNum!sixthNum&seventhNum

For Example, if 5 and 24 were entered in that order, then 7:11!13&17:19!23 would print out.

I would think to use .format but not sure on how to repeat as the list could be 5 to 56.

Also, I can't use external libraries so no numpy, sympy, itertools etc.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Use a loop jumping each 3 numbers and print with the repeating pattern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is essentially this,
**Given a list `[a,b,c,d,e,f,.....]` where a,b,c,d,e,f,.... are integers. How to obtain a string which had the flooring pattern `a:b!c&d:e!f&....`**

To do this you can just check the remainder of the index of each integer with 3 and format it accordingly.

```py
def format_str(numbers):
    result= ''
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if i%3 == 0:
            result += str(numbers[i])+':'
        elif i%3 == 1:
             result += str(numbers[i])+'!'
        else:
             result += str(numbers[i]+'&'
     return result
```

### EDIT

If you desire that the last number not be appended with any special character then you can just put in a condition like this

```py
def format_str(numbers):
    result = ''
    postfix = ''
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if i == len(numbers) - 1:
             postfix = ''
        elif i%3 == 0: 
             postfix = ':'
        elif i%3 == 1:
             postfix = '!'
        else:
             postfix = '&'
        result += str(numbers[i])+postfix
     return result
```

Comment: thank you!!! I got it to mostly work but : , ! , & is the last character like this: 7:11!13&17:19!23& but it should be  7:11!13&17:19!23.  How do i fix that?

Comment: @TCL9111 I have added an edit to the answer. Hope this helps